# Memory issues with Fat XIB

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, memory-management

i have a project with 179 xib files(ipad app).so we got memory pressure after 10 minutes once it launched.can anyone help me what should i do to solve this memory issues..i can create views programmatically, but i know it wont help me.because it will also take same memory..

At the first page it will take 250 MB to load and when i going to the inner pages memory usage getting increased.Memory is allocated at the first time when entering into a particular view controller,but when i pop from that view controller and push again to that,it is not taking additional memory.

thanks in advance..

Comment: too vague. It sounds there is memory leak.

Comment: try instruments tool to check whether you app leaks

Comment: thanks . but issues with xib files..if i reduce xib files the there is no issues..

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to run the app in instruments and profile it for memory leaks / allocations to see whats happening. Otherwise we're just stabbing in the dark here at guessing what it could be.

Profiling the app really needs to be your first step here.

Comment: Thanks..We don't have any memory leakage,all we have is memory usage

Comment: My answer still stands. Profiling the app will tell you where / how memory is allocated and if its being deallocated correctly.